# Android - Main windows seem to never have focus

Tags: android, android-activity, window, ime

I've gotten two issues recently which I suspect are related to the same fact.

The first problem: I noticed none of my EditTexts were pulling up the soft input keyboard (they always did previously), and, to test it out, I created an entirely new "default" (no custom changes) EditText and still, although the view got focus (the cursor appeared and all), the leyboard still didn't show up. Manually calling `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()` returns false too. The issue is weird because, when I call `activity.getCurrentFocus()`, I receive exactly the EditText view I was expecting, but calling `editText.hasWindowFocus()` returns false (and having window focus is a requirement for showing the IME according to documentation).

The second problem: `onBackPressed()` is never fired in any of my activities. Whether the system bars are hidden or not, or whether the back event is generated by a button or a gesture, they never get fired, which, due to the issue with the EditTexts, makes me suspect it's related to the fact my windows don't have focus.

Finding out what's wrong: I couldn't find any singular code changes I made that could impact the app in such a way, except maybe changing `targetSdk` to a level higher than my development device, but I changed it back to API 31 (my device) and no changes were made. I also tested if the issue was perhaps with my device, but deploying the app on another tablet produced the same issues. I have also thoroughly checked my manifest for potential sources of the problem, but nothing found. Is there usually a reason for why an activity's window loses focus, and a way to manually set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just found the issue. I was calling `Window.setFlags(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS, Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)` on the startup of all my activities, and, for some reason I'm yet to learn, it messed up the window focus completely. Everything works fine now though, I will edit this answer if I find the reason.